# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly...in SSIS

Tags: .net, ssis

I have a SSIS package in 2008. I have created some libraries in visual studio 2010 and complied in 3.5. I need to integrate those library in the SSIS Package. I registred those library into the GAC, but when I try to add references of those dll into the SSIS, I do not find in the Add Reference -> .Net section. Then I have to add the dll through the browse option from the compiled dll. There are no issue while compiling the SSIS. As soon as I run the SSIS package, it shows the below error

> ---
>
> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Utility, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=632cda921675b9e7' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'Utility, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=632cda921675b9e7'
>      at ST_969c7b257dd94f948f31afd96a2b2afd.csproj.ScriptMain.Main()
>
> Pre-bind state information === LOG: User = SEI-DOMAIN-1\PSaha LOG:
>   DisplayName = Utility, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=632cda921675b9e7  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/DTS/binn/ LOG:
>   Initial PrivatePath = NULL Calling assembly : (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\DTS\binn\DtsDebugHost.exe.Config LOG: Using machine
>   configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Post-policy reference: Utility, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=632cda921675b9e7 LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL
>   Server/100/DTS/binn/Utility.DLL. LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL
>   Server/100/DTS/binn/Utility/Utility.DLL. LOG: Attempting download of
>   new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL
>   Server/100/DTS/binn/Utility.EXE. LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL
>   Server/100/DTS/binn/Utility/Utility.EXE.
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture,
>   Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags
>   bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs,
>   ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[]
>   namedParams)    at System.Type.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] args, CultureInfo
>   culture)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript(

)

Comment: Did you restart BIDS after adding the assemblies to GAC ?

Comment: Yes. I restarted the SSIS. But no luck.

Comment: Try to copy Utility.EXE to directory : C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/DTS/binn/Utility/   or if still failed, try to copy to : C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/DTS/binn/

At my case, I use external library and I must copy my external library to binn folder below sql server installation directory.